# Identifying an RF connector

Tags: rf, connector

It's probably a simple question, but could you help me identify whether the connector pictured below is a type F connector? And if not what kind is it?
Thank you...

This is the link where I obtained the screenshot:
https://www.terk.com/setup/

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [Type F connector](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/F_connector) is a widely accepted 75 ohm standard for cable and antenna connections for television reception.  The connector being held in the fingertips is the male plug, and the female receptacle is mounted on the chassis.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is a type F coaxial connector.